# Create a file with only write access to system/admin in MAC

Tags: python, file-access

I have a system level process running on mac . I can create a file using
f = open(path,"w+") in python
But I want this file to be editable only by system/admin and not user.
How to achieve this in MAC using python?

Comment: You did notice the link to the duplicate which answers your question at the top…?

Comment: yes got it. Thanks